# How to update Sublime Text 3 to work with Python 3.10 syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, python-3.10

Specifically, I want to use match/case in my python code but Sublime doesn't recognize them as keywords, highlight, auto indent or anything.  How do you make the needed update?

Comment: there's a pull request for ST4 which was merged, maybe upgrade from ST3? :) https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/3015

Answer (score 0):

I think that for now the default Sublime Text 3 Python syntax highlighting is not compatible with the new features, and the best thing would be to wait for a new update or create a custom syntax highlighting based of the built in one.